# How to draw a line chart in front of a candlesticks chart

Tags: google-visualization

I want to draw a line in front of a candlesticks chart with google combo chart.

With this code, the line chart is drawn behind the candlesticks chart like the image below.

How can I change the z-axis of charts?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

      function drawVisualization() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Month', 'Low', 'Open', 'Close', 'High', 'Line'],
          ['2004/05',  80,    100,      90,    120, 1.2],
          ['2004/06',  70,    120,      95,    150, 1.8],
          ['2004/07',  60,    110,      80,    140, 1.9],
          ['2004/08',  85,    130,      92,    190, 2.8],
        ]);

        var options = {
          title : 'Candlesticks with line chart',
          hAxis: {title: 'Month'},
          seriesType: 'candlesticks',
          series: {
          1: {type: 'line', targetAxisIndex: 1}}
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: This is clearly a bug.  The default behavior should be to draw the line above the candlesticks.  There is no option to change the z-index.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a bug and belongs on the vendor support site...